# RabbitMQ Connections not auto-closed when EC2 instances is stopped or teminated

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, kombu

I'm using python's Kombu (3.0.26) with the librabbitmq connector to connect to rabbitmq in AWS on an EC2 instance.  When I start and stop the application the connection to rabbit comes up and goes away as expected.  When I kill the app with TERM or KILL again the connection goes away as expected on rabbitmq.

However if I use the AWS console to STOP or TERMINATE the instance the connection will stay around on rabbitmq for perpetuity until I go in and force the connection closed.

I might be able to solve this by adding a AMQP heartbeat on the application and figure out how to constantly ping the server that the app is still alive.  However I have some blocking calls which may prematurely kill the connection if the heartbeat does not communicate in time.  I would rather the rabbitmq server just figure out the TCP connection is dead and close the connection.

Has anyone had an issue with connections hanging around when an ec2 instance is stopped or terminated?

Comment: hi @jwieland. Have you found a solution? We're experiencing the same issue as well

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue running when ec2 spot instances were terminated in our k8s cluster.

```
kombu                                  5.2.3
celery                                 5.2.3
```

It looks like celery is creating connections with amqp heartbeats for the task consumers. However, other consumers such as the [mingle consumer](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.worker.consumer.mingle.html) have no heartbeat.

[image: rabbitmq admin connections]

There is a setting [broker_heartbeat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-broker_heartbeat) but setting this didn't seem to forward the heartbeat to the other consumers. Ultimately deep inside kombu there is a `Transport` class with a [establish_connection](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/master/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py#L198). This is where I saw that I can just proxy through a transport options from settings and they exist on at the amqp protocol level for all connections.

```py
# for celery projects
broker_transport_options = {"heartbeat": 40}

# for django + celery projects
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {"heartbeat": 40}
```

With the heartbeats set, when the node is terminated, all of the connections eventually drop from rabbitmq.